# How to Re-Evaluate CanExecute in a DelegateCommand

Tags: mvvm, prism, canexecute

I Have a table in SQL Server with some rows. I have a Prism MVVM project in WPF and Some textbox in which Text of each is bind to a property of my table.

When I Write some thing in textboxes, `canExecute` command not fired.
Why?

For examle in View:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserModel.Fname, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and a button with commad: `Command="{Binding Add_EditUserInfo}"`

in Viewmodel, I have a propert for my table:

```cs
private TblUserInfo _userModel = new TblUserInfo();
public TblUserInfo UserModel
{
    get { return _userModel; }
    set
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _userModel, value);
        Add_EditUserInfo.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

and for button:

```
public DelegateCommand Add_EditUserInfo { get; set; }
```

and in constructor:

```cs
Add_EditUserInfo = new DelegateCommand(OnAdd_EditUserInfo, CanAdd_EditUserInfo)
                           .ObservesProperty(() => UserModel);
```

for canExecute:

```cs
private bool CanAdd_EditUserInfo()
{
    return UserModel.TblUserInfo_IsValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserModel` property does not change, thus no `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`.

You have to do that inside `Fname`'s setter or attach a handler to `_userModel.PropertyChanged` and call `Add_EditUserInfo.RaiseCanExecuteChanged`from there.

When going for the handler-option, keep an eye on the lifetimes of your objects, because you might introduce a memory leak.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but pay attention that I am not to create property for each of my table fields in my ViewModel and going to bind the, directly to below property as Dexcribed previosly:     private TblUserInfo _userModel = new TblUserInfo();
    public TblUserInfo UserModel
    {
        get { return _userModel; }
        set
        { 
            SetProperty(ref _userModel, value);
            Add_EditUserInfo.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

Comment: It won't work then, because it's not meant to work the way you think it does. Binding to `UserModel.Fname` means binding to `Fname` essentially, `UserModel`'s setter will not be called.